How to call a Firebase Function httpCallable in a Flutter front app on the Firebase Emulator Suite environment?
I have set up the Firebase Emulator Suite, and the database-triggered functions are working as expected. However, I'm having trouble calling a Firebase Function using httpsCallable from my Flutter front-end app within the emulator environment. The function does not seem to respond, and I'm not sure if it's a configuration issue or something else.
enter image description here
Ensured the Firebase Emulator Suite is running with the functions emulator started on port 5001.
Configured my Flutter app to use the local emulators using useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001).
Verified that database-triggered functions work as expected in the emulator, which suggests that the emulator is functioning properly.
Tried calling the function from the Flutter app, but it throws a FirebaseFunctionsException with the error [firebase_functions/unavailable] helps litte.
main.dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(...); // I did deliver my option

  FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
  FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
  FirebaseStorage.instance.useStorageEmulator('localhost', 9199);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase Test App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;
  String _result = '';

  Future<void> regeneratePIN(String formerPIN) async {
    try {
      final HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('replacePIN');
      final response = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
        'formerPIN': formerPIN,
      });
      setState(() {
        _result = 'New PIN: ${response.data['newPIN']}';
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _result = 'Error: $e';
      });

      rethrow;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
              child : TextField(
                onSubmitted: regeneratePIN,
              ),

debug console:
FirebaseFunctionsException ([firebase_functions/unavailable] UNAVAILABLE
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:22:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _MyHomePageState.regeneratePIN (package:sapor_firebase/main.dart:56:24)
<asynchronous suspension>

terminal:
PS C:\Users\jose.lee\dev\$PROJ_NAME> firebase emulators:start
(node:17992) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting, pubsub, storage
!  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, dataconnect
(node:17992) [DEP0044] DeprecationWarning: The `util.isArray` API is deprecated. Please use `Array.isArray()` instead.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
+  firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150.
i  pubsub: Pub/Sub Emulator logging to pubsub-debug.log
i  hosting[my-app]: Serving hosting files from: public
+  hosting[my-app]: Local server: http://127.0.0.1:5000
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\jose.lee\dev$PROJ_NAME\functions" for Cloud Functions...
!  functions: Your requested "node" version "18" doesn't match your global version "22". Using node@22 from host.
Serving at port 8207

(node:14412) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

+  functions[us-central1-scheduleInactivationForWebEditPIN]: firestore function initialized.
i  functions[us-central1-inactivateWebEditPIN]: function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.
+  functions[us-central1-replacePIN]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-app/us-central1/replacePIN).

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000/               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ 127.0.0.1:9099 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth      │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions      │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore      │ 127.0.0.1:8080 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Hosting        │ 127.0.0.1:5000 │ n/a                             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Pub/Sub        │ 127.0.0.1:8085 │ n/a                             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Storage        │ 127.0.0.1:9199 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/storage   │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150


Could you share your code for the http callable function? Also, when accessing the function url "http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-app/us-central1/replacePIN", does it respond with a 400 status code? Opening it via browser should show a Bad Request error.
